# minus 1 second from one column

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am getting one field value as below from sources:

```
id | cr_date
-----------------------
1  | 19.06.2021
----------------------
2  | 01.01.2021
```

I need to subtract 1 second from `cr_date`. Also, I want to calculate one more value that will display the last day of previous month with `23:59:59` appended to it.

I tried below which did not work

```scala
val df2 = spark.sql ("""select cr_date ,
        from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col(cr_date)).minus(60), "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") as cr_date_new ,
        rundate,
        LAST_DATE(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(rundate,"yyyyMMdd")+1 -1/24/60/60,-2))
""")
```

The output I want is:

```
id | cr_date    | cr_date_new     | rundate |last_date
-------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 19.06.2021 |20210618T23:59:59|20210727 |20210531T23:59:59
-------------------------------------------------------------
2  | 01.01.2021 |20201231T23:59:59|20210727 |20210531T23:59:59
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think the last_date value for row 2 should be `20201231T23:59:59` instead of being the same value as the previous row

Comment: @user8582197 did the proposed answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

The following uses `LAST_DAY`, `CAST` and `intervals` to derive your desired results.

```sql
SELECT 
    id, 
    cr_date, 
    (cast(to_date(cr_date,'d.M.y') as timestamp) - interval 1 second) as cr_date_new,
    rundate,
    (cast(LAST_DAY(to_date(cr_date,'d.M.y') - interval 1 month)+ interval 1 day as timestamp) - interval 1 second) as last_date
FROM 
    my_data
```

#### Full reproducible example with results

```py
sparkSession.sql("""
WITH my_data AS (
    SELECT 1 AS id, '19.06.2021' as cr_date UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS id, '01.01.2021' as cr_date
)
SELECT 
    id, 
    cr_date, 
    (cast(to_date(cr_date,'d.M.y') as timestamp) - interval 1 second) as cr_date_new,
    rundate,
    (cast(LAST_DAY(to_date(cr_date,'d.M.y') - interval 1 month)+ interval 1 day as timestamp) - interval 1 second) as last_date
FROM 
    my_data
""").show()
```

```
+---+----------+-------------------+-------------------+
| id|   cr_date|        cr_date_new|          last_date|
+---+----------+-------------------+-------------------+
|  1|19.06.2021|2021-06-18 23:59:59|2021-05-31 23:59:59|
|  2|01.01.2021|2020-12-31 23:59:59|2020-12-31 23:59:59|
+---+----------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

#### Using `rundate` to derive last_date

```py
sparkSession.sql("""
WITH my_data AS (
    SELECT 1 AS id, '19.06.2021' as cr_date, '20210727' as rundate UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS id, '01.01.2021' as cr_date, '20210727' as rundate
)
SELECT 
    id, 
    cr_date, 
    (cast(to_date(cr_date,'d.M.y') as timestamp) - interval 1 second) as cr_date_new,
    rundate,
    (cast(LAST_DAY(to_date(rundate,'yyyyMMdd') - interval 1 month)+ interval 1 day as timestamp) - interval 1 second) as last_date
FROM 
    my_data
""").show()
```

```
+---+----------+-------------------+--------+-------------------+
| id|   cr_date|        cr_date_new| rundate|          last_date|
+---+----------+-------------------+--------+-------------------+
|  1|19.06.2021|2021-06-18 23:59:59|20210727|2021-06-30 23:59:59|
|  2|01.01.2021|2020-12-31 23:59:59|20210727|2021-06-30 23:59:59|
+---+----------+-------------------+--------+-------------------+
```

Let me know if this works for you